# With keyword when not setting fields

Tags: vb.net

I read about whether or not I should use the `With` keyword while writing my apps. The opinions seem to vary (even with questions on this site), from it's-a-ok to never-ever-use-it. I'm new to VB.NET, coming from C#, and the specific case I've been wondering about is this

```
Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As Package) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Package).GetHashCode
    With obj
        Return IIf(ReferenceEquals(obj, Nothing), 0, 23 * (.Weight.GetHashCode() + .CustomerReference.GetHashCode() + .Dimensions.Height.GetHashCode() +
               .Dimensions.Width.GetHashCode() + .Dimensions.Length.GetHashCode()))
    End With
    'Return IIf(ReferenceEquals(obj, Nothing), 0, 23 * (obj.Weight.GetHashCode() + obj.CustomerReference.GetHashCode() + obj.Dimensions.Height.GetHashCode() +
    '           obj.Dimensions.Width.GetHashCode() + obj.Dimensions.Length.GetHashCode()))
End Function
```

Does any of those 2 `Return` statements have an edge? Should I not use the `With` keyword here or is it ok?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, some people dislike it for various reasons.  Rather than the old `IIf` function though, the new(ish) `If` operator will do short circuiting

Comment: @Plutonix ah, as said I'm just starting with vb and was looking for an equivalent of C# `?` operator - found `IIF`

Comment: `IIf` is a function that evaluates both sides, so if one is null or has other issues, it can throw an exception.  The `If` operator is what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't use `IIf` anymore. The   equivalent of the C# conditional operator is the VB.NET [`If`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) which has two meanings: two arguments: the null-coalescing operator which is `??` in C#, three arguments: the conditional operator. This is short-circuating and strongly typed(as opposed to the `IIF`-function).

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok, corrected the code to use `If`, thanks!

Comment: I think that I remember something about the compiled IL being different. Using the `With` keyword does an object lookup only once as compared to multiple times for each property/method access. My memory is saying that things become more efficient at about 3 references to the same object.